# Report progress without slowing procedure

Tags: c#, encryption

Im trying to decrypt a file reporting the progress to show it in a progress bar, here is my decription function

```
private static void Decrypt(String inName, String outName, byte[] rijnKey, byte[] rijnIV)
        {
            FileStream fin = new FileStream(inName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream fout = new FileStream(outName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            fout.SetLength(0);


            byte[] bin = new byte[1048576];
            long rdlen = 0;
            long totlen = fin.Length;
            int len;

            SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();         
            CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(fout, rijn.CreateDecryptor(rijnKey, rijnIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);


            while (rdlen < totlen)
            {
                len = fin.Read(bin, 0, bin.Length);
                encStream.Write(bin, 0, len);
                rdlen = rdlen + len;
                //Call here a method to report progress
            }


            encStream.Close();
            fout.Close();
            fin.Close();
        }
```

I want to call a method to report the progress inside the loop, but depending on the response time of the method this may slow the performance of the decrypter, how can I report the progress without this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you decrypting on a background thread? How are you reporting progress? Show that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions for you:

1. In your reporting method, have it check as to how long it was since it last reported.  If it is less than, say, 0.3s, have it return without doing anything - no progress bar needs to be updated more than 3 times per second.

and/or

2. Offload the work of the reporting method onto another thread - that way the method within your loop will return immediately (your loop can continue right away).  In your method on the other thread, include a check not to start another thread (i.e. just return without doing anything) if the previous reporting thread has not completed yet.

Or simpler still, which may well work in your situation, include a counter in your loop and then every *n* times through your loop, do your progress report and reset the value of *n* to zero. Select a value for *n* by experiment, so that it updates often enough (a couple of times per second) but you are not doing more progress updates than you have to.  e.g. if your loop iterates at 3000 times per second, doing your update every 1000th time will be fine.

Comment: So i can create a thread with the report method and start it only when it's dead. Thanks!